# Getting stuck at determining bounds

Tags: integration, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

I think I know how to finish this problem, I just can't seem to figure out how to get the bounds for my substitution. Do you have any tips.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain for $u_2$ is obviously $[4,8]$ from the definition of $D$. $x_1^2-x_2^2=(x_1-x_2)\cdot (x_1+x_2)$, so the domain for $u_1$ would be $[0, 32]$.

If I may suggest, you'd get to the solution significantly easier if you made the substitutions suggested by the domain you're given, namely $u_1=x_1 - x_2$ and $u_2$ as you've defined it :)

Comment: Oh thanks now I see it. Yeah but the substitution were mandatory like this.